# display class variable values in python

Tags: python, azure-databricks

I have a class in python (eg)

```
testclass()
```

this class has some internal (private variables) which are assigned values within functions of the class.

(eg)

```
class wrapperfunction():


def testfunc():
self.__testvalue = 123
```

Is there a way i can view this variable's value from outside the class in another notebook
all code is written in Databricks and one notebook calls this class.
the notebook code is as under

```
%run ../Testnotebook/

wrapperfunction('testing')
```

Being fairly new to python i cant figure out how to view the value of a class function inside another function as shown above, in my main notebook.

I have tried the following to get all the variables, but this below code doesn't give me the value of the variable at runtime.

```
my_obj = testclass()
attribs = vars(my_obj)
```

I need to output / view the values at runtime to debug my code.

Comment: Have you done `x = wrapperfunction()` / `print(x.__dict__)`?  Your `run` code sample creates an object but immediately deletes, because you didn't store it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, here is no *private* methods and attributes in python.
Any information can be visible outside class.

So, starting private variable names from `__` is just a convention like `Please don't touch this private variable because I may change it in future without thinking about compatibility`.

`dir` function allow to get all class's attribute names:

```py
class A:

  __private_var = None

  def __init__(self):
    self.__private_var = 123

a = A()

for attr_name in dir(a):
  try:
    print(attr_name, ':', getattr(a, attr_name, 'non printable'))
  except:
    print(f'Could not print value of {attr_name}')
```

And output will be:

```
_A__private_var : 123
__class__ : <class '__main__.A'>
__delattr__ : <method-wrapper '__delattr__' of A object at 0x7fc196577fd0>
__dict__ : {'_A__private_var': 123}
__dir__ : <built-in method __dir__ of A object at 0x7fc196577fd0>
__doc__ : None
__eq__ : <method-wrapper '__eq__' of A object at 0x7fc196577fd0>
__format__ : <built-in method __format__ of A object at 0x7fc196577fd0>
__ge__ : <method-wrapper '__ge__' of A object at 0x7fc196577fd0>
__getattribute__ : <method-wrapper '__getattribute__' of A object at 0x7fc196577fd0>
__gt__ : <method-wrapper '__gt__' of A object at 0x7fc196577fd0>
__hash__ : <method-wrapper '__hash__' of A object at 0x7fc196577fd0>
__init__ : <bound method A.__init__ of <__main__.A object at 0x7fc196577fd0>>
__init_subclass__ : <built-in method __init_subclass__ of type object at 0x55877920c400>
__le__ : <method-wrapper '__le__' of A object at 0x7fc196577fd0>
__lt__ : <method-wrapper '__lt__' of A object at 0x7fc196577fd0>
__module__ : __main__
__ne__ : <method-wrapper '__ne__' of A object at 0x7fc196577fd0>
__new__ : <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x5587774d5de0>
__reduce__ : <built-in method __reduce__ of A object at 0x7fc196577fd0>
__reduce_ex__ : <built-in method __reduce_ex__ of A object at 0x7fc196577fd0>
__repr__ : <method-wrapper '__repr__' of A object at 0x7fc196577fd0>
__setattr__ : <method-wrapper '__setattr__' of A object at 0x7fc196577fd0>
__sizeof__ : <built-in method __sizeof__ of A object at 0x7fc196577fd0>
__str__ : <method-wrapper '__str__' of A object at 0x7fc196577fd0>
__subclasshook__ : <built-in method __subclasshook__ of type object at 0x55877920c400>
__weakref__ : None
```

Where `_A__private_var` is what are you looking for

Also `a.__dict__.get('_A__private_var', None)` may be used (as you can see at output above)

If method or attribute is *private*, [python changes it name as `_{CLASS_NAME}__{ATTR_NAME}`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/private-methods-in-python/) <sup><sub>(this is a new behavior I didn't know before `0_o`)</sub></sup>. So if private attribute name is known you may use construction like:

```py
priv_attr_name = '__private_var'
# Where `a` is created inside example above
# value is `123`
value = getattr(a, f'_{a.__class__.__name__}{priv_attr_name}', None)
# Same as above: value is `123`
value = a.__dict__.get(f'_{a.__class__.__name__}{priv_attr_name}', None)
```

**Notice**: `a.__dict__` is only acceptable if you set an attribute after instantiating. `a.__dict__` don't show class attibutes and only shows attributes of instance:

```py
class B:
  __priv_a = 123
  __priv_b = None
  __priv_c = None

  def __init__(self):
    self.__priv_b = 456

  def set_c(self):
    self.__priv_c = 789

b = B()
b.set_c()

print('__priv_a', b.__dict__.get(f'_{b.__class__.__name__}__priv_a', 'not found'))
print('__priv_b', b.__dict__.get(f'_{b.__class__.__name__}__priv_b', 'not found'))
print('__priv_c', b.__dict__.get(f'_{b.__class__.__name__}__priv_c', 'not found'))
```

And output will be:

```
__priv_a not found
__priv_b 456
__priv_c 789
```